# mysql 5.7 adjacent rows +-4 with row_number

Tags: mysql

part of the original table:

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|  id  | nickname | battle |  wins  | damage |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1055 | Wirfisd  |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
| 1098 | darkmoon |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
| 1177 | Aircon   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
| 3278 | Darius   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
| 3589 | Merkpad  |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
| 4470 | Teport   |  111   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |
| 5404 | Adrong   |  111   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |
| 8978 | Razor7   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

the code is working if the data is different.

I cannot find a solution when the data is the same.

basic sorting in table by **row_num** which is not present in mysql 5.7  and by **battles**. Additional sorting by wins and damage

```
(
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM (SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 AS `row_num`
    FROM table, (SELECT @i:=0) AS `RowNumberTable` ORDER BY battle DESC) t1
    JOIN table t2 ON t2.nickname = "'.$nick.'" AND t1.battle >= t2.battle
    ORDER BY battle LIMIT 4
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM (SELECT *, @n:=@n+1 AS `row_num`
    FROM table, (SELECT @n:=0) AS `RowNumberTable` ORDER BY battle DESC) t1
    JOIN table t2 ON t2.nickname = "'.$nick.'" AND t1.battle <= t2.battle
    ORDER BY battle DESC LIMIT 4
    )
    ORDER BY battle DESC;
```

I enter the nickname **Aircon** and the result should be like this:

```
+---------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| row_num |  id  | nickname | battle |  wins  | damage |
+---------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|   33    | 1055 | Wirfisd  |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
|   34    | 1098 | darkmoon |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.2 |
|   35    | 8978 | Razor7   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   36    | 1177 | Aircon   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   37    | 3589 | Merkpad  |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   38    | 3278 | Darius   |  111   | 52.08  | 1245.3 |
|   39    | 5404 | Adrong   |  111   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |
|   40    | 4470 | Teport   |  111   | 52.09  | 1245.4 |
+---------+------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: If all rows have the same `battle` value, how can you tell how they should be sorted?

Comment: wins and damage

Comment: Even with these 3 columns you still have perfect ties. How do you know, for example, that Razor7 comes before Aircon, while Merkpad comes afterwards? All 3 have the same battle/wins/damage.

Comment: in this case, additional sorting by id or nickname is needed

Comment: OK, but this is not consistent with your desired result. You would probably need to edit your question to clarify which sorting rules you want exactly, and align your expected result accordingly.